# What is the motivation of weighted integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, motivation

The weighted integral of a function $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is something like $\int_\Omega f(x)w(x)dx$.

What is the motivation of it?

Comment: Some numerical quadratures use weighted integrals (weighted inner products) to give rise to some orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: If you know something about measure theory, then $w(x) dx$ can be interpreted as a different measure. This is very useful for example in probability theory, where for instance $w(x) = c\cdot e^{-x/2}$ with some normalizing constant $c$ is a representation of the Gaussian measure which comes from the normal distribution. So the weighted integral would be something like the expected value of a random variable. But there is tones of different areas where this comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In probability theory, when a random variable $X$ has a pdf $w(x)$, we compute things like
$$
\mathbb E[\phi(X)] = \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x)w(x)\;dx.
$$

---

If $E$ is a region on $\mathbb R^3$, with mass distributed on it, but not uniformly, we can perhaps specify a density $w(x,y,z)$ for $(x,t,z) \in E$.  Then the total mass is
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^3} w(x,y,z)\;dx\,dy\,dz
$$
and we can compute moments like
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^3} x w(x,y,z)\;dx\,dy\,dz\\
\int_{\mathbb R^3} (x^2+z^2) w(x,y,z)\;dx\,dy\,dz
$$
We have lots of multi-variable calculus problems like this ... compute pressure exerted by water, where the density varies by depth.